# Correlated subqueries in HQL Select Clause

Tags: hibernate

I am trying use correlated queries in HQL (in select clause) for the first time and I am having the problem:

My HQL Query is of type :

```
SELECT CMP.id ,CMP.Name, CMP.startDate, CMP.endDate, CMPTTL.impr, CMPTTL.cnImpr,(CMPTU.id.login   
        FROM Z CMPTU 
        WHERE CMPTU.id.cId=CMP.id AND CMPTU.id.login = 'pqr@xyz.com')  
FROM X CMP, Y CMPTTL
WHERE CMP.Status = 'L' AND CMP.id = CMPTTL.Id (+)
```

As per the Hibernate Documentation "*HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.Even correlated subqueries (subqueries that refer to an alias in the outer query) are allowed.* "

But when i execute my HQl I have this Error

> "*org.hibernate.QueryException: aggregate function expected before ( in SELECT*"

I have seen the selectParser of hibernate and it expects a Aggregate function whenever "(" is encountered.

Please suggest

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you using SQL or HQL? From what I know, you can't have **(+)** for outer join in your HQL. If you remove the subquery is the remaining part working fine?

Comment: @Manu PK : I m using HQL, (+) is accepted as i am using Oracle as a database, Yes If i remove subquery then my Query works fine

Comment: I have updated the answer, let me know if that is working? If it is working fine accept the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because, you are **joining the `Z` and `id` multiple times in the same query**. I have modified your sub-query to use an alias of the join. I could not test it but hope that works.

```
SELECT CMP.id ,CMP.Name, CMP.startDate, CMP.endDate,
 CMPTTL.impr, CMPTTL.cnImpr,
   (CMPTUid.login FROM Z CMPTU join CMPTU.id as CMPTUid 
        WHERE CMPTUid.cId=CMP.id AND CMPTUid.login = 'pqr@xyz.com')  
FROM X CMP, Y CMPTTL
WHERE CMP.Status = 'L' AND CMP.id = CMPTTL.Id (+)
```